# How is the divergence of electric field related to the electric flux?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss-law

From the explanation of Maxwell's equations, I found, the flux of an electric field is mathematically represented by the by the divergence of the electric field.Then, how is the divergence of electric field related to the electric flux?

Comment: Please don't scream :-). The connection between the divergence and the flux is the [“Theorem of Gauß” or just “divergence theorem”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem). You apparently tagged the question with “gauss-law” already. Was it just a suggested tag? Otherwise you kind of answered your question already.

Comment: IT IS A SUGGESTED TAG

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP shows no research efforts.

Comment: There is a reason this is a suggested tag. Did you check out the tag description? And please, do not use all capital letters. It makes it really hard to read :-).

Answer (score 1):

> how is the divergence of electric field related to the electric flux?

You are looking for [Gauss' Law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/gaulaw.html), which should be in whatever textbook you are using as a guide to this subject:

$$\int E\cdot dA=\frac{q}{\epsilon_0},\\\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}=\nabla\cdot E$$

Comment: i know the mathematical relations but i want to know the explanation i.e.from subjective point of view...

Comment: @nelsonningombam, on the off chance you are in central Virginia, I would gladly get coffee with you and talk all about it in a very intuitive way.  Unfortunately, I can't communicate to that same standard in internet comments and I don't have any online resources to offer you since I first learned what you're asking about with friends in undergrad.  Wish I could do more; best of luck.